# Packages available in ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a list of available packages for ros2 yet? I'm tasked with evaluating how many of our current dependencies are available in ros2 and haven't been able to find a distribution list as is available with ros1 [here for kinetic](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/kinetic/distribution.yaml)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278785/packages-available-in-ros2/) by [jlack](https://answers.ros.org/users/30932/jlack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2018-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros2/rosdistro/blob/ros2/ardent/distribution.yaml

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlack](https://answers.ros.org/users/30932/jlack/) on 2018-01-04**:
Ugh I must be blind...Thanks!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-01-04**:
Also this: http://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_ardent_default.html